# Unifonic Application Integartion 403 error

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes, devops, digital-ocean

I have an application which is running on kubernetes cluster on Digital Ocean where I've configured Load balancer and ingress is also in place and I've integrated it with unifonic, where I have whitelisted all my Node's and load balancer's IP in Unifonic dashboard, I was getting notifications earlier and now after the developers have pushed some changes into the applicaiton, I am not getting the notifications, getting following error

```
[2024-01-31 03:43:16] production.ERROR: {"type":"unifonic_send_sms_failure","status":403,"body":{"mobile_number":"+966999959995","message":"<#> Thank you for your registration. Use this code: 8813 to activate your account  

 Iw1kndQa+GC"},"message":"HTTP Response Not OK"}
```

I have checked IP whitelisting, I have checked the config map and verified all the key-value pairs, rechecked the APP's ID, as per my analyses everything is in place but still I am unable to resolve the issue

Comment: Thank you for your registration. Use this code: 8813 to activate your account.

Comment: I would suggest this is an HTTP 403 [which you can find a description of here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)